# Salesforce Count # of times a Name appears in multiple columns

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

New to reporting formulas. I have a salesforce report where I have 5 columns. Where a name may appear in one of the columns 1, 2, 3,4,5 just depends. I need to create a column that will put the name in the new column if that name appears in one of the 5 columns.

For example. - I have a report that is driven off an opportunity where my team assigns onsite staff. The staff's name can appear in positions 1 - 5.  The new column I create needs to output the person's name.

Thanks for your assistance.

I have tried searching but have not found what I am looking for.

Comment: I have used the following. However SalesForce says I can only use 5 unique fields. 
IF(
    OR(
        CONTAINS(Field1__c, "John Doe"),
        CONTAINS(Field2__c, "John Doe"),
        CONTAINS(Field3__c, "John Doe"),
        CONTAINS(Field4__c, "John Doe"),
        CONTAINS(Field5__c, "John Doe")
          ),
    "John Doe",
    ""
)